# Refresh page when HTTP Post event occurs

Tags: php, http, post

I have a C# application and I send an HTTP Post to a `test.php`. You can see its full code below. Is it possible to refresh the `test.php` page (or a even better a `<div>` using jquery) when that http post event occurs ?

```
<script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<?php 
    if (count($_POST)) {
        $imageData = base64_decode($_POST['myImageData']);
        $h = fopen('test.jpg', 'w');
        fwrite($h, $imageData);
        fclose($h);
        exit('Image successfully uploaded.');
    }
    if (file_exists('test.jpg')) {
        echo '<div id="MyDiv">
                  <img src="test.jpg"/>
              </div>
             ';
        // Refresh page here perhaps like so: (everytime $POST event occurs)
        // echo `
        //      <script> $("#MyDiv").html("<img src="test.jpg"/>"); </script>
        //      `;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `if($_POST)` to see if the page is posted. If so do something

Comment: I am using `if (count($_POST))`. This only works when you first load the page. It doesn't trigger everytime Http Post event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery.post for send the post requeste and the callback function per refresh the

client side

```
$.post( "ajax/test.php", function( data ) {
   $( "#MyDiv" ).html( data );
 });
```

(data) is response form post related action in your case the server  response come eg: form text.php

server side file .../yourUrl/ajax/test.php

```
        <?php
         echo '<div id="MyDiv">
              <img src="test.jpg"/>
          </div>
         '
         ?>
```

Comment: I have uodate the answer for minor (correct  div id name)

Comment: `ajax/test.html` is the server action you invoke for obtain the data. You don't mention them and I call it so.

Comment: I have update the answer hope this is clear for you. otherwise let'me know

Comment: I am not sure you understand what I am trying to do. I have a C# application and I send an HTTP Post to a `test.php`. You can see its full code in my question. The user opens his browser and types `www..../test.php` and sees an image.  I want to refresh `<div id="MyDiv">` for the user, so that this image is refreshed, everytime HTTP Post is called from that C# application.

Comment: The title of my question: `Refresh page when HTTP Post event occurs`, describes what I am trying to do. The `HTTP Post` is happening from a C# application. Not the user.